# Dynamically add fields to dataclass objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, dynamic, field, python-dataclasses

I'm writing a library to access REST API. It returns json with user object. I convert it to dict, and then convert it to dataclass object. The problem is that not all fields are fixed. I want to add additional fields (which are not specified in my dataclass) dynamically. I can simply assign values to my object, but they don't appear in the object representation and `dataclasses.asdict` function doesn't add them into resulting dict:

```py
from dataclasses import asdict, dataclass

@dataclass
class X:
    i: int

x = X(i=42)
x.s = 'text'

x
# X(i=42)

x.s
# 'text'

asdict(x)
# {'i': 42}
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You could use [`make_dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.make_dataclass) to create `X` on the fly:

```
from dataclasses import asdict, dataclass, make_dataclass

X = make_dataclass('X', [('i', int), ('s', str)])
x = X(i=42, s='text')

asdict(x)
# {'i': 42, 's': 'text'}
```

Or as a derived class:

```
from dataclasses import asdict, dataclass, make_dataclass

@dataclass
class X:
    i: int

x = X(i=42)
x.__class__ = make_dataclass('Y', fields=[('s', str)], bases=(X,))
x.s = 'text'

asdict(x)
# {'i': 42, 's': 'text'}
```

Comment: In the case of `TypeError: non-default argument 's' follows default argument` you should add: `x.__class__ = make_dataclass('Y', fields=[('s', str, field(init=False))], bases=(X,))`

Comment: Also, just a note that in the original question, it isn't too clear why a solution with `dataclasses` is desired. I've actually opted with a slightly different approach, that should be overall much faster than `make_dataclass`. I've updated my answer below to reflect this as well.

Comment: going to this effort contradicts the convenience and benefit of dataclasses. they are there to simplify classes and make data structures clear and easy. . .  https://youtube.com/live/0lCIkY32AdI?feature=share

Comment: How about the new class name 'Y', how do you use it?

Comment: You could give the dataclass its own identifier on creation, if you would like to: `Y = make_dataclass(...)` and `x.__class__ = Y`, or `y = Y(i=42, s="foo")`.

Answer (score 11):

**Update (6/22)**: As it's now mid-2022, I thought I'd refresh my answer with a brand new approach I've been toying around with. I am pleased to announce a fast, modern library I have quite recently released, called [`dotwiz`](https://pypi.org/project/dotwiz/).

The `dotwiz` library can be installed with **pip**:

```
pip install dotwiz
```

This is a tiny helper library that I've created, which makes `dict` objects safe to access by dot notation - such as `a.b.c` instead of `a['b']['c']`. From personal tests and benchmarks, it's actually [**a lot** faster](https://dotwiz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/benchmarks.html#results) than something like [`make_dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.make_dataclass) - more info on this below.

Additionally, one can also subclass from `DotWiz` or `DotWizPlus`, and this enables type hinting and auto-completion hints from an IDE such as PyCharm. Here is a simple example of that below:

```py
from dataclasses import asdict, make_dataclass

from dotwiz import DotWiz


class MyTypedWiz(DotWiz):
    # add attribute names and annotations for better type hinting!
    i: int
    s: str


dw = MyTypedWiz(i=42, s='text')
print(dw)
# ✫(i=42, s='text')

print(dw.to_dict())
# {'i': 42, 's': 'text'}
```

*If you still prefer to use dataclasses* to model your data, I've included my original answer below that is mostly unchanged from years past.

#### Benchmarks

The follow results were timed on a Mac Pro with the M1 chip, Python 3.10.4, and with `n=5000` iterations.

**Creating or instantiating the object:**

```
$ python -m timeit -n 5000 -s "from dotwiz import DotWiz" -c "DotWiz(i=42, s='text')"
5000 loops, best of 5: 425 nsec per loop

$ python -m timeit -n 5000 -s "from dataclasses import make_dataclass" -c "X = make_dataclass('X', [('i', int), ('s', str)]); X(i=42, s='text')"
5000 loops, best of 5: 97.8 usec per loop
```

These times are probably inflated, but in this particular case it looks like `DotWiz` is about **250x** faster than `make_dataclass`. In practice, I would say it's about 100 times faster on average.

**Accessing a key by dot notation:**

```
$ python -m timeit -n 5000 -s "from dotwiz import DotWiz" -s "dw = DotWiz(i=42, s='text')" -c "dw.s.lower()"         
5000 loops, best of 5: 39.7 nsec per loop

$ python -m timeit -n 5000 -s "from dataclasses import make_dataclass" -s "X = make_dataclass('X', [('i', int), ('s', str)])" -s "x = X(i=42, s='text')" -c "x.s.lower()"
5000 loops, best of 5: 39.9 nsec per loop
```

The times to access an attribute or a key look to be mostly the same.

**Serializing the object to JSON:**

```
$ python -m timeit -n 5000 -s "import json" -s "from dotwiz import DotWiz" -s "dw = DotWiz(i=42, s='text')" -c "json.dumps(dw)"
5000 loops, best of 5: 1.1 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit -n 5000 -s "import json" -s "from dotwiz import DotWiz" -s "dw = DotWiz(i=42, s='text')" -c "json.dumps(dw.to_dict())"
5000 loops, best of 5: 1.46 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit -n 5000 -s "import json" -s "from dataclasses import asdict, make_dataclass" -s "X = make_dataclass('X', [('i', int), ('s', str)])" -s "x = X(i=42, s='text')" -c "json.dumps(asdict(x))"
5000 loops, best of 5: 2.87 usec per loop
```

So, it actually looks like it's about  **2.5x faster** to serialize a `DotWiz` object, as compared to a `dataclass` instance.

#### Original Answer

As mentioned, fields marked as optional should resolve the issue. If not, consider using properties in `dataclasses`. Yep, regular properties should work well enough - though you'll have to declare field in `__post_init__`, and that's slightly inconvenient.

If you want to set a default value for the property so accessing getter immediately after creating the object works fine, and if you also want to be able to set a default value via constructor, you can make use of a concept called field properties; a couple libraries like [dataclass-wizard](https://pypi.org/project/dataclass-wizard/) provide
full support for that.

example usage:

```py
from dataclasses import asdict, dataclass
from typing import Optional

from dataclass_wizard import property_wizard


@dataclass
class X(metaclass=property_wizard):
    i: int
    s: Optional[str] = None

    @property
    def _s(self):
        """Returns a title-cased value, i.e. `stRiNg` -> `String`"""
        return self._s.title() if self._s else None

    @_s.setter
    def _s(self, s: str):
        """Reverses a string, i.e. `olleH` -> `Hello` """
        self._s = s[::-1] if s else None


x = X(i=42)

x
# X(i=42, s=None)

assert x.s is None  # True

x.s = '!emordnilap'

x
# X(i=42, s='Palindrome!')

x.s
# 'Palindrome!'

asdict(x)
# {'i': 42, 's': 'Palindrome!'}
```

---

*Disclaimer*: I am the creator (and maintener) of this library.

Comment: Adding reference to (claimed) impressive benchmarks (comparing performance to make_dataclass, Box, DotMap, and maybe others): https://github.com/rnag/dotwiz#benchmarks. (Partial motivation for my writing this comment: I want a web-search hit on `dotwiz & dotmap`.)

Comment: dotwiz sounds nice, but really needs to be part of a standard library or method of dataclass as opposed to a satellite import (which gives up convenience). In fact, dataclass should now be a python keyword . . .  https://youtube.com/live/0lCIkY32AdI?feature=share